# Powershell/Regex to count number of times a date range appears

Tags: regex, powershell, select-string

I am working on a script to pull metrics from a log file. Here is an example from the log.

```
2/21/2022 3:29 PM: Requested username - Found disabled account with matching CATIID named username - Account username reactivated

3/21/2022 3:37 PM: username - No account found. Creating new account.

4/26/2022 1:25 PM: username- Disabled account found. Re-enabling 
account.

4/26/2022 1:25 PM: username - Active account found. Added to requested groups and updated charge code.

4/26/2022 1:25 PM: username - Disabled account found. Re-enabling account.
```

I need to be able to filter this to only count the number of times "Reactivated or Re-enabling" appears but also only for the month we are auditing.

Expected count from above would be 2 for the month of April.

I attempted to start filtering by using

```
$acc1 = Get-Content $accountcreatedpath | Select-String -pattern "$reactivationmonth/"
$acc2 = $acc1 | Select-String -pattern "/2022"
$acc3 = $acc2 | Select-String -NotMatch "$reactivationmonth/2022"
$accountscreated1 = ($acc3).Count
```

However this will miss any entries that occur when the month and day are the same. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: With `(?m)^4/\d{1,2}/20\d{2}.*?\b(Reactivated|Re-enabling)\b` regex, you [can get](https://regex101.com/r/icKORt/1) the two matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$acc1 = '2/21/2022 3:29 PM: Requested username - Found disabled account with matching CATIID named username - Account username reactivated
3/21/2022 3:37 PM: username - No account found. Creating new account.
4/26/2022 1:25 PM: username- Disabled account found. Re-enabling
account.
4/26/2022 1:25 PM: username - Active account found. Added to requested groups and updated charge code.
4/26/2022 1:25 PM: username - Disabled account found. Re-enabling account.'
$reactivationmonth=4
$rx = "(?m)^$reactivationmonth/\d{1,2}/20\d{2}.*?\b(Reactivated|Re-enabling)\b"
([regex]::Matches($acc1, $rx )).count
```

Output is `2`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/icKORt/2).

*Details*:

- `(?m)^` - start of a line (`(?m)` equals `RegexOptions.Multiline` option)
- `$reactivationmonth` - the month
- `/` - a `/` char
- `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `/20` - a `/20` text
- `\d{2}` - two digits
  -`.*?` - any zero or more chars other than newline chars as few as possible
- `\b(Reactivated|Re-enabling)\b` - a whole word `Recativated` or `Re-enabling`.

Comment: Just FYI: you might consider trying out a multiline supporting pattern like `(?ms)^4/\d{1,2}/20\d{2}(?:(?!^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/20\d{2}).)*?\b(Reactivated|Re-enabling)\b` if you have trouble with the one in the answer.

Comment: Hi, how could I use this method pulling directly from the .txt file? I tried with Get-Content and Out-String but it doesn't seem to work as expected like in your example.

Comment: @Rich With `([regex]::Matches((Get-Content text.txt -Raw), $rx )).count`